# How can I speed up the loading of images from a web service?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, performance

I'm new to iPhone development. In my application, I had kept a scrollview and I have loaded the images from web service using JSON parsing. Unfortunately, it is taking too much time to load them. Do you have any suggestions on how to speed up the (down)loading?

Comment: JSON is a text format not a binary image format.  Streaming data, is a thread intensive, asynchronous operation in its best form.  Perhaps you could share your code so that it would be easier to see the exact problem.  There are many iOS frameworks to help you deal with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well there can be many routes you can take to make image loading faster but the one thing I would recommend most is utilize AFNetworking's `"UIImageView+AFNetworking"` category which you can find here:

http://afnetworking.com/

It loads images quickly and doesnt tie up the main thread. If you have a preloader image you want to display while it is downloading you can do that as well.

AND it's really easy:

```
[imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"…"]];
```